# pulp produces meaningless constraints when using empty list comprehensions

Tags: list-comprehension, pulp

I am solving a forestry LP with PuLP, and wasted many hours figuring out why CPLEX was producing meaningless answers. Essentially I had some variables unattached to the rest of the problem because of empty list comprehensions. My constraints are always of the kind:

```
for year in YEARS:
    lp+=pulp.lpSum([vol[i]*x[i] for i in possible_combinations 
                    if test(i)])==yearly_volume[year], "yearly_volume[%d]" %(year)
```

And in some cases the condition defining the list comprehension (test) was never fulfilled, thus leading to unattached variables. Does anyone else think PuLP should warn us when this happens? I should end up with a constraint that looks like

```
0==yearly_volume[2025]
```

but the constraint is not added instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0==yearly_volume[2025]`

was originally what happened and then someone suggested that technically it is

`None == yearly_volume[2025]`

Which could be interpreted as an empty constraint

I take your point about a warning though maybe start an issue on the github repo. Or even better a pull request

Thanks

Stu